# ImageMagick: when cropping and merging multiple PNG images into a single PDF, pages are shifted out of view

Tags: merge, png, crop, imagemagick-convert

I have multiple screenshots, saved as PNG, which I want to batch-crop and merge into a single PDF. Given the required offset and size, cropping is simple enough:

```
mogrify screenshot01.png -crop 123x456+42+42
```

This crops a 123×456-pixel image from the screenshot, with its top-left corner 42 pixels from both the top and left edge, and overwrites the existing file.  (Note: if you don't want to overwrite your original, use `convert` instead of `mogrify`.)

Then, merging the screenshots into a single PDF should also be easy:

```
convert screenshot*.png merged.pdf
```

...however, this results in a file where all pages are slightly shifted out of view.  Why does this happen, and what should I do to prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When cropping an image, the offset (+42+42 in the example) is stored in the resulting PNG file:

```
$ identify screenshot01.png
screenshot01.png PNG 123x456+42+42 DirectClass 8-bit 42.4Ki 0.000u 0m:0.000007s
```

And then, when merging, ImageMagick honours this offset.  The offset is also reported by `gimp` when opening the file, asking you whether to apply it; other applications like `gThumb` silently ignore it, though.

To remove the offset, use the `+repage` option, either when cropping...

```
mogrify screenshot01.png -crop 123x456+42+42 +repage
```

...or when merging:

```
convert +repage screenshot*.png merged.pdf
```